# SciFi movie where a guy gave up his prison sentence in exchange for his body to be used or his consciousness

Tags: story-identification, movie, crime

I'm pretty sure it was futuristic. Had flying cars in it. Guy gave up his prison sentence in exchange for either his body to be used or his consciousness. It was something about clones or conscious transfer/prolonging life.

It's not *Selfless*, *Upgrade* or *Altered Carbon*. It was 2005-2019.

Comment: This is a nice start but if you remember anything else you can [edit] your question to add that detail in. Remember each detail you add the more likely it is someone will be able to identify this for you. For example, how was his body/consciousness used? How did he give them up? What does exchanging them for his prison sentence mean in this context? How did he end up in prison? What happened after this? Was this guy the main character?

Answer (score 1):

Not certain if it has flying cars (still researching), but that sounds a bit like the plot of *[Gamer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamer_(2009_film))* from 2009.

> In 2034, [computer programmer] Ken Castle (Michael C. Hall) invents self-replicating nanites that replace brain tissue and allow humans to control other humans' actions and see through their eyes. The first application of Castle's "Nanex" technology is a virtual community life simulation game, Society, which allows gamers to manipulate live actors as their avatars. Society becomes a worldwide sensation, making Castle the richest man in the world. He then creates Slayers, a first-person shooter where the "characters" are death-row prisoners using real weapons in specially created arenas. Unlike Society actors, Slayers participants are not paid; instead, they volunteer in exchange for the promise that any Slayer who survives 30 matches will earn his freedom (though no one ever has).
>
> John "Kable" Tillman (Butler) is the crowd's favorite, having survived a record 27 matches (no inmate before him has managed to last more than ten). He is exclusively controlled by Simon (Lerman), a seventeen-year-old superstar gamer from a wealthy family.

### Trailer

Ah, and with a bit of further exploration, there are no clones or life-extension, just nanite-based mind control. Still, this fits as a decent partial answer in the right timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

[Altered Carbon  (TV series 2019-2020)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2261227/?ref_=kw_li_tt)

*"ALTERED CARBON is set in a future where consciousness is digitized and stored in cortical stacks implanted in the spine, allowing humans to survive physical death by having their memories and consciousness "re-sleeved" into new bodies. The story follows specially trained "Envoy" soldier Takeshi Kovacs, who is downloaded from an off-world prison and into a combat ready sleeve at the behest of Laurens Bancroft, a highly influential aristocrat. Bancroft was killed, and the last automatic backup of his stack was made hours before his death, leaving him with no memory of who killed him and why. While police ruled it a suicide, Bancroft is convinced he was murdered and wants Kovacs to find out the truth."*

Episodes [Out of the Past](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5989942/keywords?ref_=tt_stry_kw) (the pilot) and [Rage in Heaven](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6720042/keywords?ref_=tt_stry_kw)  have keyword "flying-car"

You probably just saw one episode of this show.

Comment: OP was fairly adamant that it's *not* Altered Carbon.

Comment: Oh, fair enough. Description fits, though.

Comment: If it really does fit, it generally doesn't hurt to posit it. If nothing else, it may help someone else.